# Typescript variable is declared but never used for string interpolation

Tags: typescript

I'm getting `[ts] 'imgNum' is declared but never used.` for the following code where I'm trying to construct an image src string:

```
let imgNum: string = [...].toString();
imgSrc = '${imgNum}of5.png';
```

How do I get it not to raise the error when I'm actually using that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but Typescript is right, you are not using the `imgNum` variable, you are assigning to `imgSrc` a string.

You want to use ` (backtick) instead of `'` if you want to include the variable

```
let imgNum: string = [...].toString();
imgSrc = `${imgNum}of5.png`;
```

```js
let imgNum = 2;
let imgSrc = '${imgNum}of5.png';
let imgSrc1 = `${imgNum}of5.png`;

console.log(imgSrc);
console.log(imgSrc1);
```